# SQL query to achieve results?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Suppose we have a table-

```
T1
1
2
3
4
```

We want to write a above query to achieve below results-

```
T1     T2
1       1
2       1
2       2
3       1
3       2
3       3
4       1
4       2
4       3
4       4
```

Please Help

Comment: What have you tried. Also you need to format your code, and give us a table structure of some sort.

Comment: Also, you have multiple SQL tags, you need to pick the one you are actually using. Is it SQL Server 2008, or PostgreSQL?

Comment: hi chili, i am new on this forum, i have just edited, please review once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a `join`:

```
select t1.t1, t2.t1 as t2
from atable t1 join
     atable t2
     on t2.t1 <= t1.t1
order by t1, t2;
```

The trick is the inequality in the `join`.

Comment: Removed as @GordonLinoff changed answer to be correct

Comment: i have tried this but not giving correct results

Comment: @skcwebworld . . . I misread the result set.  I just modified the query to use `join` instead.

Comment: now working fine..thanks Linoff and KHeaney.